# Symfony form entity collection custom object builder

Tags: php, forms, events, symfony

My application handle multiple shops by host routing, thus almost every table have `shop_id`. Now, there I have categories and separate form to manage them by `CategoriesType`.

```
$builder->add('categories', 'bootstrap_collection', array(
        'type' => $this->categoryType,
        'allow_add' => true,
        'allow_delete' => true,
        'error_bubbling' => false,
    ));
```

categoryType is a `Type` which is constructed with current shop with data_class set to Category entity. BUT that needs shop_it to be properly stored in DB.

Question is, how to embed a logic to alter object before form is valided - how to use setShop() on new entity.

Here is how I use it:

```
$categoriesForm = $this->createForm(new MenuCategoriesType(
    $this->get('form.category_type')
), $catering = $this->getUser()->getCatering());
$categoriesForm->handleRequest($request);

if ($categoriesForm->isValid()) {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($catering);
    $em->flush();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually I do it with [PostPersist](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/events.html#postupdate-postremove-postpersist) Event.

Comment: One of the options but I used cascade doctrine annotation along with orphan removal set to true